# Website analytic software compliance

Tags: seo, analytics

I need to find a program which can crawl a site and show what various search engine spiders will parse (or not parse) and use for information.

What we are looking to do is have a program go through the our site and tell us what images don't have alt tags (because engines use the alt tags on images at times to determine some site information etc.), or which content is written such a way that the SEs can't pull the information and use it in their rankings.

Answer (score 3):

#### OPTIONS

- Google

  - **Google Webmasters**, an online software to monitor your sites content on the Google Search Engine.
  - The Google option has a feature that shows the webmaster how the search engine sees the website's pages.
  - https://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/
  - https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/
  - http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster
- Yahoo : there's Yahoo Site Explorer
- Bing :  there's also an online app

Comment: Y! Site Explorer has been merged into Bing Webmaster Tools, but good answer.